# Proguard obfuscates google's classes and ignore -keep

Tags: java, android, proguard

In my project, I don't want proguard to obfuscate my Log class, so I use

`-keep class org.core.sandfall.game.utils.Log  {
    public static void e(java.lang.String);
}`

and it works.

I also don't want proguard to obfuscate google's leaderboard, specifically the method submitScore (for my own project).

No matter what -keep I use, it obfuscates it!

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl$* {
    *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl {
    *** *submitScore(...);
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl {
    *** *submitScore(...);
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.*$* {
    *;
}
```

I tried using them separately or all together, with no luck.
What am I doing wrong (where did I mistype)?

**Edit:**

`-injars ../Sandfall/lib/google-play-services.jar` couses proguard to crash (`-verbose` doesn't say why), and

`-outjars ../Sandfall/lib/google-play-services.jar` or

`-libraryjars ../Sandfall/lib/google-play-services.jar` doesn't work, although proguard runns.

**Edit (2):** for some odd reason,

`-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}`

keeps SafeParcelable , but

`-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl {
    public void submitScore(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String, java.lang.Long);
}` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly, what I did was write **only**

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.**{*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl {
    public void submitScore(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String, java.lang.Long);
}
```

and that worked!